# Python Selenium - [Error 5] Access is denied when trying to quit a browser instance

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I don't know why, but I got this error a lot recently(not every time):

```
Access is denied: 'c:\\docume~1\\shanew~1\\locals~1\\temp\\tmpijz7zu\\cookies.sqlite-shm'
```

code is like:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
...
browser.quit()
```

Anybody knows how to fix this?

P.S.: The program is running on a VirtualBox win XP professional 32 bit, the only thing I did recently was update the driver to make it compatible with multiprocessors. Maybe it has something to do with above errors?

Comment: How are you running the test? It can be because a driver instance has been left behind.

Comment: @Arran: What do you mean by "left behind"?

Comment: Doesn't close/quit/dispose itself properly.

Comment: @Arran: I don't think so. There's nothing been changed in the codes, the only thing I did was change XP from "ACPI computer" to "ACPI multiprocessor computer". Although these two things does not seem to have anything related, I just couldn't figure out why. The problem is like come out of no where...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have administrative/IO access to the cookies file, you can get this error. You can get around this by specifying a folder local to wherever you're running your script from to store options.

Alternatively, you can run your script under administrative mode, and it should work just fine.

Comment: I believe I do have administrative access to everything, that file including the full folder can be easily deleted manually, just don't know why python throws out this error. By the way, how do you run the script under administrative mode in XP?

Comment: @Shane Run your script as admin (as it was suggested). Or change the security setting of the file so "Everybody" can "read" it. (but running as admin is better)

Comment: @Shane In that case, use the first suggestion.  You shouldn't be using the machine copy of your browser for testing; what you should do is create an install of your browser local to the directory you keep your scripts in, and specify that install by modifying the browser options.